# Install side Python module from Github to Anaconda

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I'd like to install side module located on GitHub (https://github.com/mokelly/wabbit_wappa)

Could someone help me with conda commands useful for those purposes, please?

```
conda install wabbit_wappa
```

is not working as there is no such package on the site. I'm using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the package you are trying to use does not support Python 3, as indicated by the implicit relative import you got when you tried to [install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647036/install-side-python-module-from-github-to-anaconda#comment38205560_24647360) (these are no longer supported in Python 3).

You can create a Python 2 conda environment with

```
conda create -n py2 python=2.7 anaconda pip
```

(you can replace `anaconda` with specific packages you want to install), and then

```
source activate py2
```

will activate it. You can then

```
pip install wabbit_wappa
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use pip install when a module isn't available via conda.

Comment: I've done that. But once `import wabbit_wappa` command sent I saw the following error: `File "/Users/sas/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wabbit_wappa/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    import active_learner

ImportError: No module named 'active_learner'
`

Comment: Have you tried the [installation instructions](https://github.com/mokelly/wabbit_wappa#installation) in that repository? They have two more options you can try.

Comment: Are you sure that package supports Python 3? That looks like an implicit relative import, suggesting that it doesn't.